# Extract list items from a string

Tags: c#

I have a line like

"In this task, you need to use the following equipment:

1. Perforator
2. Screwdriver
3. Drill

After finishing work, the tool must be cleaned."

How do I extract elements from this string? As a result, I need an array like {"Perforator", "Screwdriver", "Drill"}

Comment: What exactly do you know about the format of the input string? Is it always that exact phrase, followed by a numbered list?

Comment: srk, no. There can be any characters before and after the list. But there can be only one list per line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do this using regular expressions (assuming the input text is similar to your example and there is always numbering in front of each item):

```
string input = @"
In this task, you need to use the following equipment:

1. Perforator
2. Screwdriver
3. Drill

After finishing work, the tool must be cleaned.";

string pattern = @"(\d\. )([a-zA-z]*)";
var results = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Groups[2].Value); // ...or insert each in a List
}
```

Result:

```
Perforator
Screwdriver
Drill
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do it would be to break the string into lines, then try to convert each line into a number plus text, and take only the lines where the conversion is successful.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetNumberedItems(string input)
{
    var lines = input.Split(new [] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        var items = line.Split('.');
        if (items.Length != 2) continue;
        var ok = int.TryParse(items[0].Trim(), out _);
        if (ok) yield return items[1].Trim();
    }
}
```